# Vertically center image relative to text that takes the rest of the parent's width?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to achieve this layout without display:table?

I want the blue box (the image / icon) on the left to be always vertically centered relative to the text on the right, even if the text takes up more than one line. Additionally, I want the text to be able to fill up the remainder of the parent container's width.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2zts0ob/)

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class="table">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="cell1">
                <div id="image"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="cell2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.table {
    display: table;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
}

#cell1 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#cell2 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#image {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: inline-block` instead on your elements which you need to vertically align with respect to each other. Here's an example:

```css
.table {
  display: block;
}
.row {
  display: block;
}
#cell1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#cell2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 1%;
  width: 60%;
}
#image {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="cell1">
        <div id="image"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="cell2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j2zts0ob/2/)**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion! But the text does not fill the remainder of the parent's width. It's only 60%.

Comment: You can try using the `float` CSS property but then the box won't be vertically aligned with the text therefore your best bet is to use your existing HTML and CSS i.e. the `display: table` method to vertically center the box with the text and make the text occupy the remaining width.